Received invalid block tag 4. Latest block number is 0
I am new to hardhat. I ran into this issue and don't know how to handle it.
I install node.js on my Windows, node version 17.9.1 and install npx.
And then use
npx hardhat create-react-app AppName
Then I start the node using
npx hardhat node
Well it gives me some accounts. and I import one of the accounts into Metamask. (network http://127.0.0.1:8545 with chain ID 31337), then I see
eth_blockNumber (13)
eth_getBalance

     Received invalid block tag 4. Latest block number is 0

and I cannot see the balance of my account,

What does this Received invalid block tag 4. Latest block number is 0 mean and I want to see the balance of the account.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Go to MetaMask > Settings > Advanced > Reset Account. This will clear the MetaMask cache in your browser and reload data from the Hardhat instance.
Next:

Stop your local Hardhat network by stopping the terminal running
Hardhat.
Clean the cache in your root directory:
npx hardhat clean


Recompile your contract:
npx hardhat compile


Restart your Hardhat node by running:
npx hardhat node



